# Magento Error Grand Total and SubTotal are being Doubled

Tags: magento

Hi I am using Magento for our online store and have an issue unique to some users where the price of every product and shipping is doubled in both the cart at the top right and when placing an order at the end.

See the attached screenshot:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Here some users means specific type of customer group ?

Comment: Please check cart rule price and I think there mention shipping fee.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed any third party extension related with Cart or Checkout ?

If Yes, please disable it and check once again. May be there is some bug in that extension.

If no, then check your local modules, may be your Totals is being overridden.

The things I have mentioned is just for debugging to reach out the place where the problem is occurring from.

Thanks.